# In general, how do you index something in database queries? How do you know what to index?

Tags: sql, database, indexing

Can anyone direct me to an easy to understand explanation (that doesn't require me to read a 300-page tome) about how to index things and how to identify what to index, what it means to normalize things, etc? Or provide very simple examples?

Comment: If you think 300 pages is a tome, then you are lost. I wrote a [book on that topic](http://sql-performance-explained.com/) and I think it is as short as it can be to **understand** indexing. Still it has about 200 pages. You can read it for free at http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is strictly for **SQL Server**

1. for every "serious" data table, there **must be** a well-chosen clustering index. A **good** clustering index is narrow, unique, static (never changes) and ideally ever-increasing - an `INT IDENTITY` is as close to perfect as it can be
2. For any column that is a **foreign key**, create a nonclustered index. This helps JOINs and other operations and is a generally accepted best practice
3. **Don't OVER-INDEX!** - too many indices can be worse than none!
4. Let your system run for a while, observe how it performs, identify potential performance bottlenecks
5. if you have identified some performance issues, generate a representative workload (not just a single query; by using server-side tracing) and try to optimize that by using e.g. the Data Tuning Advisor (but *don't blindly adopt* everything the DTA says!)
6. Implement **one index** at a time - observe your system again - did the performance (real or perceived) improve? If so: leave the index - if not: remove it again

Which indexes exactly to use - that's a bit of a black art based on a lot of know-how, experimentation, experience - you really can't give clear, black-or-white kind of ideas here. Try something - observe its benefit (or negative impact) - learn from it. Repeat until your retirement :-)

There's really no 10-page checklist and once you know that, you're done. Either you learn these things yourself, over the years - or you hire someone who has that expertise - your choice. There's no "easy way" to mastering everything about indexing in 5 easy lessons.....

Comment: The problem I have is that I have no idea how to even begin learning any of this. I am not sure what kind of data I should "experiment" with, what to practice with, etc.

Comment: @user3219632: well - do you currently **have** a system with performance issues? It's always best to learn on a real, practical example. Otherwise: read, read, read! Lots of good blogs out there - or if you can, attend a course on SQL performance tuning techniques to learn the basics

Answer (score 0):

Paul Litwin's Fundamentals of Relational Database Design is worth a read if you're starting from scratch. (22 page tome...) http://sbuweb.tcu.edu/bjones/20263/Access/AC101_FundamentalsDB_Design.pdf

And as he says, database design is more art than science, so examples will only get you so far with improving your own system(s).